# Display table and map from an ajax script

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp page which displays the nearest fast foods in a map with marks and in table with columns:

```
<table id="fastfood">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
</tr>
```

I want to display them via an ajax,but I dont know how to do it exactly and what to write in data..the ajax file is connected with a servlet by url which return the list with the nearest fast foods (Id, Name, Address) in a json form. My ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'PostFastFoodAjax.java',
    type: 'json',
    data: {

       latitude: pos[0],    //The coordinates of the place which I am right now
       longitude: pos[1],

     },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        drawTable(data);
        drawMap(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data){
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#fastfood").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.address + "</td>"));
}
```

Comment: the code is fine. what is the problem you are having???

Comment: `console.log(data)` in `$ajax.success`, then have a look in your dev tools console. You might just need to step in an object or two to get what you want to render out. ie. `data.restaurants`.

Comment: Please at least add JSFiddle link (You may give dummy data ) so that people can help you solve the problem. As code seems Ok.